# Change the location of the linked tables all at once in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010, database-migration, linked-tables

I have an Access database that I need to move from one server to another and therefore the path of the linked tables will need to change to the new location and I wonder if there is any way to do this for all the tables at once instead of using the Linked Table Manager and update them one by one.

Comment: The Linked Table Manager does not limit you to updating only one link at a time.  You can click the `Select All` button to tell it you want to update all the linked tables.

Comment: If you want to update the links with VBA code, see http://allenbrowne.com/ser-13.html  You can find other code examples by searching Stack Overflow.